# I can't connect mysql with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I can't connect mysql to rails ,i have tried to modify database.yml and gemfile but nothing works.Please help.

**Rails Environment Configuration**

```
git:
  version:    git version 1.7.6.msysgit.0

ruby:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe
  version:    ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

rails:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rails.bat
  version:    Rails 3.1.1
```

**Process**

```
C:\Sites>cd demo

C:\Sites\demo>rake db:migration
rake aborted!
Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the
client library is 5.0.27.

(See full trace by running task with --tracing)
```

i have installed mysql 5.5

Comment: Post content of `database.yml` and output of `rake db:create`

Comment: any errors that show in your terminal would also be helpful. Sometimes the mysql gem isnt installed or you haven't run rake db:migrate.

Comment: Is mysql installed? Is it running?

Comment: I have run rake db:migrate and says mysql2 adapter is not installed.I have tried bundle install and says mysql2 is not part of the bundle so it cannot be installed.I have tried a lot of things because i have read and other forums but the problem remains.

Comment: which version of rails your are using

Comment: Until you get the MySQL versioning issue worked out you can use Sqlite; at least you can get started.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the Client Library which is libmysql.dll.

Try downloading version 6 from here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

And change your current file with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
database yml

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: railsapp
  encoding: utf8
  username: root
  password: 1234
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: mysql2
   database: railsapp
   encoding: utf8
   username: root
  password: 1234
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
   adapter: mysql2
    database: railsapp
    encoding: utf8
    username: root
  password: 1234
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```